# Replace all captured groups but first in sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, replaceall

I am trying to replace a list of numbers, into "a" letter.

I have been able to do this already in an online regex tester as you can find [here](http://regexr.com/3snv6).

> Example: 123,456,789 ==> 123,a,a

But, I translated this into sed command, like this, and it's not working.

```
echo "123,456,789" | sed 's/\(\d*\)\(,\d*\)/\1,a/g'
```

Which produces:

> 123,a456,a789

Am I missing something?

Comment: Use `sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\(,[0-9]*\)/\1,a/g'`

Comment: see also: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Comment: also note that `echo "123,456,ABC" | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\(,[0-9]*\)/\1,a/g'` will give `123,a,aABC` because `*` quantifier matches **zero** or more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple `sed` might help you:

```
$ sed -r 's/,[0-9]+/,a/g' <<< "123,456,789"
123,a,a
```